# Code promotion plan from dev to live for wordpress

Tags: linux, wordpress, inotify

We are having wordpress multi-site and the developers do there development on dev server, We are not using any version control for wordpress development, I need some plan so we can move the site from dev to live fast and secure.

I was thinking about inotify + rsync but what about the db promotion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually we do  wordpress multisite development in dev.example.com and then need to move to live site which is www.example.com, so we need to change all the links in the files and db both from dev.example.com to www.example.com and move the mysql from dev server to the live. Currently I am doing that manually but now I found wordpress plugin named duplicator, that works for me including the links changes and mysql export/import etc.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duplicator/

More detailed answer and other plugins look for the following question.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119/how-to-easily-move-a-wordpress-install-from-development-to-production

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge and research. There are apparently many ways to solve this problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has a simple 503 "maintenance" page which you can (and should) enable during a code deployment. If you upgrade WordPress from within itself, then it enables and disables this page automatically.

If you want to enable it yourself, simply create a blank file `.maintenance` in the top level WordPress directory, and delete it when the deployment is complete.

Example:

```
touch /srv/www/example.com/.maintenance
rsync staging@staging.example.com:/srv/www/example.com /srv/www/example.com
# custom scripts here, if any
rm /srv/www/example.com/.maintenance
```

At this time, a WordPress user with the Administrator role must now visit `http://example.com/wp-admin/network/upgrade.php` (for multi-site; remove `/network` for a single site) to update the database schema. I don't know of any good way to do that offline; however WordPress is pretty good at continuing to work with an out-of-date schema.

Comment: Thanks Michael but the answer I was looking for I found on the wordpress forum I answered my own question if you can verify that.